# Fastest Algo to separate the 0s and 1s

Tags: program-optimization

Suppose, I have an array of length 100.
I have 0s at some positions and 1s at some other positions.
What is the ***fastest method*** by which I can separate the **0s** and **1s**, so that we get all the 0s at the beginning and all the 1s at the remaining positions / vice-versa?

Comment: you can just rewrite the array to a new array that has 50 zeros and then 50 ones...

Comment: Are any other data associated to the 0 and 1? If not, just go through the array counting the zeroes, and then rewrite the array with that number of zeros and fill with ones. This is linear, and can't be beat (up to a constant factor), as you need to look at the whole array anyway.

Comment: It sounds like the asker may be looking for a practical solution not a theoretical solution.  Perhaps [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) may be a better place to ask about the fastest implementation of "sheep and goats"?  They have a number of questions on [popcount](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=population+count+[bit-manipulation]) but none that I could find on sheep and goats.

Comment: @vonbrand Basically [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)? Although the wikipedia implementation actually moves the keys (with associated information).

Comment: By the way, this bit separation operation is also referred to as centrifuge (i.e., in addition to sometimes being called sheep and goats).

Comment: Voted to close as off topic. There are many algorithms for the problem. The way I see it, you want a method that is practical. If that is the case, the question would be a better fit for StackOverflow, and depend on the programming language.

Comment: If you are working with C/C++, there are blazingly fast bit counting operations, see [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive). Then, you could initialize to new array to zeros. Finally, copy as many ones to the array as you counted earlier using [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).

Comment: @Juho I don't think the question is off topic.
However, Thanks for replying.

Comment: Actually, I wanted a practical solution in Java and C++.
But don't want to use an inbuilt method/function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another version of Yuval's algorithm that uses two loops only.

```
int number_of_ones = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++ i)
{   number_of_ones += A[i];
    A[i] = 0;
}
for(i = 100 - number_of_ones; i < 100; ++ i)
{   A[i] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
i=0, j=size(ar)-1;
while(true)
   increase i to position of first 1;
   decrease j to position of first 0;
   if(i>=j) break;
   ar[i]=0, ar[j]=1;
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question.
I have updated it correctly now.
Please reply.

Comment: I don't see any difference in your question and I think that my answer still applies.

Comment: It's not fastest according to me.
If yes, can you please help me in understanding?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially Quicksort. And unless OP clarifies _much_ more,the solution I give in my comment is still the most efficient possible...

Comment: Only those slots are assigned to which are not right at the beginning. Each assignment is part of the final result. It checks all values in single pass (starting at both ends and halting in the middle). So I don't see a single superflous instruction to optimize away. What do you mean that it's not fastest? Got a faster solution already?

Comment: @vonbrand First, this depends on what you are counting. Your solution needs an assignment for every single element while mine only assigns those which are not right already. Also, while your solution is linear, it still needs two passes while the result can be achieved in a single pass. Finally, your solution is non-destructive which can be either a pro or a con, depending on the situation.

Comment: @vonbrand Also, while my solution resembles the quicksort partitioning process, I think it's misleading to call it "essentially quicksort", as the performance characteristics are different (linear instead of `Nlog(N)`).

Comment: In C++, the `partition` function from [<algorithm>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) does exactly this.

Comment: I downvoted because the answer only gives program code. What does the code do? How do you argue this is the "fastest" method? In particular, why is this better than some other algorithm?

Comment: @adrianN This implementation in C++ is marked as a "possible implementation". Actual implementation, while likely to be similar, is not not necessarily this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is vonbrand's solution.

```
int C = 0, i;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  C += A[i];
C = 100 - C;
for (i = 0; i < C; i++)
  A[i] = 0;
for (; i < 100; i++)
  A[i] = 1;
```

This solution has the advantage that we only scan the array forwards. Also, there are no conditionals.

The idea can be adapted to arrays with any constant number of values, say decimal digits. Instead of `C += A[i]`, you use `C[A[i]]++`.

Comment: You can do this with 2 loops.

Comment: We're trying to avoid ifs at all costs, though Intel CPUs have SETxx instructions which would be useful here. We could use A[i] = (i >= C), though I see that you had an even better suggestion in mind.